# BadPaddingException: Blocktype mismatch: 0

Tags: android, encryption, cryptography

So i have a android to PC communication ( android = client, PC = server )
and when the client tries to connect to the server this is thrown at the server:

```
javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Blocktype mismatch: 0
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpadV15(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpad(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.doFinal(RSACipher.java:356)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.engineDoFinal(RSACipher.java:382)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2087)
```

but the same code for a pc client succesfully connects to the pc server ( PC <-> PC Works, Android <-> PC doesnt )

Is there any difference in the android crypto that could cause this? I dont post any code since the code is huge and the 1:1 copy on the PC client works flawless.

Server method to decrypt the packet:

```
public static Packet decompile(PacketWrapper wrapper, PrivateKey privateKey)
        throws Exception {
    for (Provider provider : Security.getProviders()) {
        System.out.println(provider.getName());
        System.out.println(provider.getInfo());
        System.out.println(System.lineSeparator());
    }
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
    byte[] data = cipher.doFinal(wrapper.data);
    return (Packet) bytesToObj(data);
}
```

Client method when sending the packet:

```
try {
    KeyGenerator kg = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
    kg.init(AESsize, new SecureRandom());
    aesKey = (SecretKeySpec) kg.generateKey();
    new SecureRandom().nextBytes(ivKey);

    out.writeObject(Packet.compile(new ClientKeyPacket(aesKey, ivKey),
            publicKey));
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    print("Could not connect to the server");
    closeStreams("");
    return;
}
```

where `Packet.compile()` is:

```
public static PacketWrapper compile(Packet packet, PublicKey publicKey)
        throws Exception {
    byte[] bytes = objToBytes(packet);
    System.out.println("Size > " + bytes.length);

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
    byte[] data = cipher.doFinal(bytes);
    return new PacketWrapper(data);
}
```

and the `Crypt` static strings are:

```
public class Crypt {
    public static String saltMethod = "PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1";
    public static String encryptMethod = "AES/CBC/NoPadding";
    public static String shortEncrypt = "AES";
    public static String encoding = "UTF-8";
    public static int saltIterations = 5000;
    public static int saltLength = 8;
}
```

Comment: I don't know if anybody can help you without the actual code. Can you boil the problem down to a minimal working (i.e. broken in this case ^^) example?

Comment: Of course there are differences, numerous differences. The most common problems I see across platforms is the default platform character set. If you are using, *anywhere* in your code, either the no-args String.getBytes() method or the single argument String(byte[]) constructor then you are in a state of sin.

Comment: i checked the byte[] on both sides, they are identical, but cipher.doFinal throws that exception, and with differences i thought if the crypto had some notable changes which could cause this.

Comment: Maybe the Android library defaults to "textbook" RSA and the Java version to PKCS#1 v1.5 when you do `Cipher.getInstance("RSA")`? You should always spell out your full intentions: `Cipher.getInstance("RSA/None/PKCS1Padding")`, or if you are programming a new system, preferably `Cipher.getInstance("RSA/None/OAEPPadding")`.

Comment: ups, scratch, that, its "RSA" currently

Comment: I've voted to close. We can't answer this without some code examples. Please take the time to produce a minimal working example - it's worth the effort.

Comment: From your posted code it seems you use AES for encryption and RSA for decryption. This clearly cannot work.

Answer (score 1):

Many things can cause a `BadPaddingException`.  To diagnose them, temporarily set your decryption method to `NoPadding`.  That will allow it to run to completion and give you some output to examine.  Look at the last block of the decrypted message.

If you see the tail end of your message plus some good padding, then set your decryption method to expect that padding.

If you see complete garbage, then you have an earlier problem, unrelated to padding.  Check that **everything** is byte-for-byte identical on both sides: key, IV, message.  As @GregS pointed out, default character encodings are a common offender here.  In general, defaults are a bad thing.  Different systems have different defaults, so always explicitly specify what you are using: character encoding, Cypher mode, padding, KDF etc.  Not working across different systems is often a symptom of mismatched system defaults.

Finally, when you have diagnosed the problem, set you padding back to something other than `NoPadding`.

Comment: Seems like the Bouncy Castle provider does the debugging for you - check out my answer:)

Answer (score 0):

By default Android uses a heavily edited Bouncy Castle provider as implementation for many cryptographic algorithms. This is probably also the case for RSA for your version of Android. Now Bouncy Castle FAQ #4 states:

---

If you create the cipher using:

```
Cipher rsaCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA", "BC");
```

It is actually up to the provider to decide what sort of padding you get. In the case of the BC provider this is none at all, equivalent to:

```
Cipher rsaCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/NONE/NoPadding", "BC");
```

---

This is an insecure RSA version without padding.

Replace both RSA strings by `"RSA/NONE/PKCS1Padding"` and you should not get the exception anymore. Do *not* use the `"BC"` provider indicator, let JCA find the algorithm implementation for you.

Try not to rely on default values in cryptography.

Comment: `javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded` - does this mean i forgot to replace somewhere or? (I used your `"RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding" ` suggestion) but in the server generation i left 

`KeyPairGenerator kg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");`

Comment: Try `"RSA/NONE/PKCS1Padding"` maybe. I thought that ECB was the common mode, but I might have been mistaken there. Oh, bugger, and remove the `"BC"` from the `getInstance()` call too.

Comment: We are still having problems with android-server communication, if you could provide some more input it would be awesome!